# Reverse even numbers (Only) from given Singly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I want to reverse even numbers in a singly linked list in java, but I face some difficulty to get the correct output.
For example,
input : 2, 18, 24, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6, 12
the method should reverse the even numbers ***only*** which are  {2,18,24} and {6,12}

**the correct output** : 24 , 18 ,2 , 3 , 5 ,7 , 9 , 12 , 6

**But,my output: 24 18 3 5 7 9 12 6 which it is wrong**

the main method

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SLL<Integer> p = new SLL<Integer>();
    int[] e = { 2, 18, 24, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6, 12,5 ,4 ,3 ,2,6,8};

    for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        p.addToHead(e[i]);

    }
    p = reverse(p);
    p.printAll();
}
```

**This is the method (that doesn't work correctly)**

```
  public static SLL<Integer> reverse(SLL<Integer> p) {
    SLL<Integer> returnList = new SLL<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<Integer>();

    for (SLLNode tmp = p.getHead(); tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
        if ((((Integer) tmp.info) % 2) != 0) {
            returnList.addToHead((Integer) tmp.info);
            p.deleteFromHead();

        } else if ((((Integer) tmp.info) % 2) == 0) {
            stk.push((Integer) tmp.info);
            p.deleteFromHead();

        }
        if (stk.getLSize() >= 2) {

            while (!(stk.isEmpty())) {
                returnList.addToHead((Integer) stk.pop());
            }

        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

this is the SLLNode class

```
public class SLLNode<T> {

public T info;
public SLLNode<T> next;
public SLLNode() {
    this(null,null);
}
public SLLNode(T el) {
    this(el,null);
}
public SLLNode(T el, SLLNode<T> ptr) {
    info = el;
next = ptr;
}
```

}

this is the SLL class

```
public class SLL<T> {

protected SLLNode<T> head, tail;

public SLL() {
    head = tail = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}

public void addToHead(T el) {
    head = new SLLNode<T>(el, head);
    if (tail == null)
        tail = head;
}
public SLLNode getHead(){
    return head;
}

public void addToTail(T el) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        tail.next = new SLLNode<T>(el);
        tail = tail.next;
    } else
        head = tail = new SLLNode<T>(el);
}

public T deleteFromHead() { // delete the head and return its info;
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;
    T el = head.info;
    if (head == tail) // if only one node on the list;
        head = tail = null;
    else
        head = head.next;
    return el;
}

public T deleteFromTail() { // delete the tail and return its info;
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;
    T el = tail.info;
    if (head == tail) // if only one node in the list;
        head = tail = null;
    else { // if more than one node in the list,
        SLLNode<T> tmp; // find the predecessor of tail;
        for (tmp = head; tmp.next != tail; tmp = tmp.next)
            ;
        tail = tmp; // the predecessor of tail becomes tail;
        tail.next = null;
    }
    return el;
}

public void delete(T el) { // delete the node with an element el;
    if (!isEmpty())
        if (head == tail && el.equals(head.info)) // if only one
            head = tail = null; // node on the list;
        else if (el.equals(head.info)) // if more than one node on the list;
            head = head.next; // and el is in the head node;
        else { // if more than one node in the list
            SLLNode<T> pred, tmp;// and el is in a nonhead node;
            for (pred = head, tmp = head.next; tmp != null
                    && !tmp.info.equals(el); pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next)
                ;
            if (tmp != null) { // if el was found;
                pred.next = tmp.next;
                if (tmp == tail) // if el is in the last node;
                    tail = pred;
            }
        }
}
public void printAll() {
    for (SLLNode<T> tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        System.out.print(tmp.info + " ");
}

public boolean isInList(T el) {
    SLLNode<T> tmp;
    for (tmp = head; tmp != null && !tmp.info.equals(el); tmp = tmp.next)
        ;
    return tmp != null;
}

public int length() {
    int length = 0;
    for (SLLNode tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {

        length += 1;
    }
    return length;

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to determine your output? 
The reverse method returns a SLL<Integer> object, which does not seem to have a simple method to show the result.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: The SLL class doesn't appear to have a printAll method. Can you show the code for that too?

Comment: I'm so sorry. you can find it now in SLL class

Comment: thanks - if you add a `p.printAll();` before your  `p=reverse(p)` you'll see that the input is actually `12 6 9 7 5 3 24 18 2`. This will be because you're using addHead() rather than addTail() to create the input. I get the same output as you now.
My suggested answer below seems to work fine for me. The output will show as `6 12 9 7 5 3 2 18 24`, which is what I'd expect from the input of `12 6 9 7 5 3 24 18 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your reverse method gives me a different output to what you see. So, I suspect you got your output from slightly different code.

I get : 24, 6, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 18

In your reverse method you start adding even numbers to your returnList  when you have 2 on the stack. If you want to reverse all even numbers you need to wait until you have all the continuous even numbers on the stack. Or in other words, when you get an odd number, or there are no numbers left, you can pop all the even numbers back off the stack..

I think you should also use addTail rather than addHead.

So something like

```
public static SLL<Integer> reverse(SLL<Integer> p) {
    SLL<Integer> returnList = new SLL<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<Integer>();

    for (SLLNode tmp = p.getHead(); tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next) {
        if ((((Integer) tmp.info) % 2) != 0) {
            // add any stacked even numbers
            while (!(stk.isEmpty())) {
                returnList.addToTail((Integer) stk.pop());
            }
            // add the odd number
            returnList.addToTail((Integer) tmp.info);

        } else if ((((Integer) tmp.info) % 2) == 0) {
            System.out.println("even " + tmp.info);
            stk.push((Integer) tmp.info);

        }

    }
    // add any remaining even numbers from the stack
    while (!(stk.isEmpty())) {
        returnList.addToTail((Integer) stk.pop());
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I made it using list of python, I just wanted to know whether I could write this program without using a linked list or not. The complexities may be high, but it is just an experimental implementation which works**

```
arr = [2,18,24,3,5,7,9,6,12]
arr_final = []
temp = []
for i in arr:
    if i%2 == 0:
        temp.append(i)
    else:
        if temp!=[]:
            temp.reverse()
            for j in temp:
                arr_final.append(j)
            temp = []
        arr_final.append(i)
if temp!=[]:
    temp.reverse()
    for j in temp:
        arr_final.append(j)
    temp = []

print(arr_final)
```